# Detect sequential numbers in a 4 character string (C# or SQL)

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a text box with a mask that requires 4 digits. How can I determine whether or not a sequence was entered (1234, 6789, 5432, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Is 2468 a sequence too? What about 1345?

Comment: What about "8901" - is wrapping allowed?

Comment: what about 1793?  it's not a nice neat mathematical sequence, but it's the four corners of the keypad in clockwise order.

Comment: Another is 1011.. does the sequence go beyond 0-9?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
bool textIsSequential = 
  "0123456789".Contains(text) || "9876543210".Contains(text);
```

If wrapping is allowed, just repeat the sequence in the test string: e.g. `"01234567890123456789"`

Comment: Very smart answer , nice one

Answer (score 4):

For the SQL bit follow the same approach as the other answer:

```
'0123456789' LIKE '%' + text + '%' OR '9876543210' LIKE '%' + text + '%'
```

Thanks for AakashM for pointing out my terrible SQL and the threat of SQL injection with the above approach  :)

Comment: You'll need `'%' + text + '%'` I think, and so you'll have to worry about injection...

Comment: +1 @leppie: With regards to your rollback of my answer, I just wanted to clarify that it wasn't me who edited your answer into mine; it was someone else. Cheers.

Comment: @Ani: I saw it was not you  :)

Comment: @AakashM: I agree, but you could do that at parameter level. I'll modify answer.